# Outlook "event listener" to reply to email using address in the rec'd email

Tags: vba, outlook, event-listener

I receive an alert from a SharePoint site and extract the "Requestor Email" and "Submitter Email" from the body of the SharePoint alert email.  These emails become the TO: and CC: of an email that Forwards the SharePoint Alert.

I can get the macro to work on it's own, but not "automatically" when the email is rec'd in outlook.

I macro fires BUT it doesn't work on the most recently received or new alert email.  The Forward email generates from a previously received (and read) email and keeps generating the Forward email from the same previous email.

I thought NewMailEx would address the issue of the macro not firing on the most recently rec'd (or new email), but it's not.

This is the code that I pasted to ThisOutlookSession

```
Option Explicit

Private objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Private WithEvents objNewMailItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
Dim objMyInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objMyInbox = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set objNewMailItems = objMyInbox.Items
Set objMyInbox = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)

Call OnetimeFwdSelToAddr

End Sub
```

And OnetimeFwdSelToAddr is here (I didnt include the parsing function parsetextlinepair...that part seems to work just fine)

```
Sub OnetimeFwdSelToAddr()
Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
Dim objItem As Object
Dim objFwd As Outlook.mailitem
Dim strAddr As String
Dim strAddr2 As String
On Error Resume Next
Set objOL = Application
Set objItem = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
If Not objItem Is Nothing Then
    strAddr = ParseTextLinePair(objItem.Body, "Requestor Email:")
    strAddr2 = ParseTextLinePair(objItem.Body, "Submitter Email:")
    If strAddr <> "" Then
        Set objFwd = objItem.Forward
            With objFwd
            .HTMLBody = "edited out my email text here" & vbCr & .HTMLBody
            .SentOnBehalfOfName = "othermail@asdf.com"
            End With
        objFwd.To = strAddr
        objFwd.CC = strAddr2
        objFwd.Display
    Else
        MsgBox "Could not extract address from message."
    End If
End If
Set objOL = Nothing
Set objItem = Nothing
Set objFwd = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Current process: No need for `Split`.

```vb
Private Sub xApplication_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)

    Dim objItem As Object
    
    Set objItem = Session.GetItemFromID(EntryIDCollection)
    Debug.Print "NewMailEx " & objItem.subject

End Sub
```

NewMailEx https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.newmailex

Old process:

```vb
Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String) 
    Dim varEntryIDs 
    Dim objItem 
    Dim i As Integer 
     
    varEntryIDs = Split(EntryIDCollection, ",") 
     
    For i = 0 To UBound(varEntryIDs) 
        Set objItem = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(varEntryIDs(i)) 
        Debug.Print "NewMailEx " & objItem.Subject 
    Next 
     
End Sub
```

You would pass objItem as a parameter rather than `Set objItem = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)`.