# Inbox Rule "on this computer only" that runs a macro fails periodically

Tags: vba, outlook, dns, rules

I have an Inbox rule that runs when a message arrives "on this computer only" which executes a macro.

The macro extracts the domain from the sender's email address. It also overrides the Exchange emails from internal users to "Exchange".

This allows me to have a custom field in the Inbox with the domain of the sender of email. I use that for a number of things including sorting, categorization, etc.

It periodically fails. I need to capture more information about what message causes it to fail to find a pattern and possibly a fix.

```vb
Public Sub ExtractDomain(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

  Dim oProp As Outlook.UserProperty
  Dim sDomain

  sDomain = Right(Item.SenderEmailAddress, Len(Item.SenderEmailAddress) - InStr(1,Item.SenderEmailAddress, "@"))
  If Item.SenderEmailType = "EX" Then sDomain = "Exchange"
  Set oProp = Item.UserProperties.Add("Domain", olText, True)
  oProp.Value = sDomain
  Item.Save
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox Err.Description
  End If
  Err.Clear

End Sub
```

When it fails I go into Rules, edit the rule, change nothing but save it again, re-enable it and then it runs until the next time.

I removed `On Error ResumeE Next` and added the MsgBox for the error. I got the same thing. A dialog box titled "Rules in Error" with two columns Rule and Error which say "Extract Domain" and "The operation failed" respectively.

I was also told of a better way to identify the Exchange Email so I am no longer parsing the `sDomain` value I parsed from `SenderEmailAddress`. I am using this instead:

```
If oMail.SenderEmailType = "EX" Then sDomain = "Exchange"
```

**Code above is edited to reflect what is currently running.**

I've been watching my Inbox to catch when it failed and have two examples, both were Internet email addresses, not Exchange email addresses. I looked at the Email Internet Headers and tried to see if there is an issue with the Sender info. It is not clear where Outlook gets the SenderEmailAddress which I am parsing but I suspect it's the SMTP "From: " value. One of the failed messages was from Microsoft and shows this value:

From: "quarantine@messaging.microsoft.com" quarantine@messaging.microsoft.com

I added an ad hoc macro to pull the domain and populate the User Property for one or more selected emails and it works on the same emails that triggered an error when the code above was executed by the Inbox Rule. The other macro looks like this:

```vb
Sub ListSelectionDomain()
  Dim aObj As Object
  Dim oProp As Outlook.UserProperty
  Dim sDomain
  For Each aObj In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
    Set oMail = aObj
    sDomain = Right(oMail.SenderEmailAddress, Len(oMail.SenderEmailAddress) - InStr(1, oMail.SenderEmailAddress, "@"))
    If oMail.SenderEmailType = "EX" Then sDomain = "Exchange"
    Set oProp = oMail.UserProperties.Add("Domain", olText, True)
    oProp.Value = sDomain
    oMail.Save
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      MsgBox Err.Description
    End If
    Err.Clear
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Add an actual error handler and write the info to a file, or pop up a messagebox?

Comment: It is rare for rule errors to be explained. Try ItemAdd [How do I trigger a macro to run after a new mail is received in Outlook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263483/how-do-i-trigger-a-macro-to-run-after-a-new-mail-is-received-in-outlook) or NewMailEx [Outlook "event listener" ... rec'd email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20671358/outlook-event-listener-to-reply-to-email-using-address-in-the-recd-email).

Comment: Since you proved with `Sub ListSelectionDomain()` the code is reliable on received mail, run it after the mail is in the inbox [How to replace the "Run as Script" functionality...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45743223/how-to-replace-the-run-as-script-functionality-in-outlook-2016-rules)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `On Error Resume Next` and see if you get a better error. Or actualy display the error:

```
Public Sub ExtractDomain(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

  Dim oProp As Outlook.UserProperty
  Dim sDomain
  On Error Resume Next

  sDomain = Right(Item.SenderEmailAddress, Len(Item.SenderEmailAddress) - InStr(1,Item.SenderEmailAddress, "@"))
  If Left(sDomain, 66) = "/O=EXCHANGELABS/OU=EXCHANGE ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP (xxxxxxxxxxxxx)" Then sDomain = "Exchange"
  Set oProp = Item.UserProperties.Add("Domain", olText, True)
  oProp.Value = sDomain
  Item.Save
  if Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox Err.Description
  End If
  Err.Clear

End Sub
```

I suspect you get an error when adding the user property.

Comment: Well, they were good ideas but they did not help... I did both, commented out "RESUME NEXT" and added the MsgBox for the error. All I got is the same thing I always get when it errors. a dialog box titled "Rules in Error" with two columns Rule and Error which say "Extract Domain" and "The operation failed" respectively.